# Failed to instantiate module [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I received this error upon upgrading from AngularJS **1.0.7** to **1.2.0rc1**.

Answer (score 404, accepted):

The ngRoute module is no longer part of the core `angular.js` file. If you are continuing to use $routeProvider then you will now need to include `angular-route.js` in your HTML:

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular-route.js">
```

[API Reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

You also have to add `ngRoute` as a dependency for your application:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', ...]);
```

If instead you are planning on using [`angular-ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) or the like then just remove the `$routeProvider`  dependency from your module `.config()` and substitute it with the relevant provider of choice (e.g. `$stateProvider`). You would then use the `ui.router` dependency:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', ...]);
```

Comment: Seems like the `ui-router` project may be a more flexible alternative, if you're starting from scratch (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: @gatoatigrado - I just realised how old the `ui.state` syntax was when I upgraded my app from `angular-ui-router` **v0.0.1** to **v0.2.0**, which means it now uses the `ui.router` name. My apologies for any confusion caused.

Comment: Where is the CDN address for `angular-route.js`?

Comment: @SaharSany - The [documentation for `angular-route`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) gives the CDN address as well as other options. As for [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) there is currently no CDN that I know of.

Comment: `ui-router` doesn't seem to be on its own CDN, though it is on cdnjs: http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-router

Comment: Calling a page reload with ui-router seen at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/angular-js-angular-ui-router-reloading-current-state-refresh-data

Answer (score 41):

adding to scotty's answer:

Option 1:
Either include this in your JS file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Option 2:
or just use the URL to download '[angular-route.min.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js)' to your local.

and then (whatever option you choose) add this 'ngRoute' as dependency.

explained:
`var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);`

Cheers!!!

Comment: Sorry but I have to admit that this seems very similar to the answer already provided??

Comment: ...at other places I found that people are not able to find the link/ URL to download or refer the 'angular-route.min.js'. 
That's what I gave in Answer and Yes I agree to 'ngRoute' Dependency you talked about, so I added that too in My answer.

Comment: I am more than a bit tired of js library hell. Surely there has to be a better way than figuring out the proper stack module by module.

Comment: This is how it's done @SamanthaAtkins, If you know what's needed you inject the dependency and include the JS file if you don't have code for that Dependency. Although I'd appreciate a better way if someone suggests.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was because the file was minified with wrong scope. Use Array!

```
app.controller('StoreController', ['$http', function($http) {
    ...
}]);
```

Coffee syntax:

```
app.controller 'StoreController', Array '$http', ($http) ->
  ...
```