# AngularJS: Argument 'Controller as short' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a hard time to figure out what the problem is.

Why does this code (index.html) run

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
      <section ng-controller="TabController as tab">
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

while

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <section ng-controller="TabController as tab">
      </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

produces a error: ´Error: Argument 'TabController as tab' is not a function, got undefined at Error (native)´

app.js:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

  app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.products = gems;
  });

  app.controller("TabController", function() {
    this.tab = 1;

    this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
      return this.tab === checkTab;
    };

    this.setTab = function(setTab) {
      this.tab = setTab;
    };
  });

  var gems = [
    {
      data : 'data'
    }
  ];
})();
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the availability of features in your version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is caused because you're referencing Angular 1.0.6. "Controller as" syntax is not available in Angular pre 1.2.0. If you change 1.0.6 to 1.2.0 it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, the update also made this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481863/failed-to-instantiate-module-injectorunpr-unknown-provider-routeprovider necessary