# Injecting Angulartics

Tags: angularjs, angulartics

I am having issues injecting Angulartics into my application. When I include Angulartics, I get the following error:

> Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams <- $route

I am following this [guide](http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/).

This is my code snippet for injecting the dependencies in app.js:

```
angular.module('parrotApp',
['parrotApp.filters', 'parrotApp.services', 'parrotApp.url', 'parrotApp.directives',
  ... 
 'lvl.directives.dragdrop', 'ui.bootstrap',
 'ui.compat', 'spinner.directive', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'angularFileUpload',
 'angular-hallo', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination', 'ui.grid.autoResize',
 'ui.grid.selection', 'angulartics', 'angulartics.google.analytics'])

.config([
   '$routeProvider', '$stateProvider', 'QUERY_PARAMS', '$httpProvider',

         /**
          * Define the routings
          * @param $routeProvider
          * @param $stateProvider
          */
   function($routeProvider, $stateProvider, QUERY_PARAMS, $httpProvider) {
    ...
   })
]);
```

This is my code snippet for including the dependencies in home.jsp:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
    <script src="/app/lib/analytics/analytics.js"></script>
    <!-- Angulartics -->
    <script src="/app/lib/analytics/angulartics.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/lib/analytics/angulartics-ga.js"></script>
```

I double checked the paths to ensure they are correct. I have included angularjs, and the other angular dependencies seem to work fine. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to download and include angular-routescript after angularjs and set `ngRoute` dependency as well in the module.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to instantiate module \[$injector:unpr\] Unknown provider: $routeProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481863/failed-to-instantiate-module-injectorunpr-unknown-provider-routeprovider)

Comment: I'm using UI-routing instead of ngRoute, would I still need to include ngRoute? And if so, could you explain why if I were to remove the angulartics dependencies the app works fine?

Comment: You will have to look at angulartics it must be having dependency on angular-route. Also you are injectng $routeProvider in the config as well.